# Are transitions from a broad quantum state to itself possible?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, nuclear-physics, resonance

If you have a broad quantum state (e.g. a nuclear resonance) and you populate that resonance at the high energy end - is it quantum mechanically possible for the state to decay "into itself", just with a lower energy (e.g. via an M1 gamma transition)